# Could't import aar into a library project in android studio

Tags: android, aar

I have a library project projectA, projectA needs to use a third library `thirdparty.aar` and `thirdparty1.jar`. Library projectA will be exported as sdk with extension file name `aar`(`projectA.aar`).

I create a sample project to test my `projectA.aar`. `thirdparty1.jar` works fine in my `projectA.aar`, but `thirdparty.aar` doesn't work in my sample project even sample project has compile error.

can't not resolve package for thirdparty.aar

Anyone know how to import a `thirdparty.aar` file into my library project like importing jar file(jar file works file), and package this `thirdparty.aar` with my own library.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the below steps should generally work.

1) Add the thirdparty.aar file in libs folder.

2) Use "New Module" option under File menu and Import the .aar file.

3) Build gradle and compile the project.

Also mention the gradle version that you are currently using if you face any issues on this further.